# How to beamer \alert code snippets in lhs2TeX?

Tags: beamer, lhs2tex

How to highlight particular ranges of lhs2TeX code in beamer?

Naive example (to be preprocessed with `lhs2TeX --agda`):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
%include agda.fmt
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{spec}
somefunction :  {-"\begin{alertenv}"-}importantaspect{-"\end{alertenv}"-}
                secondline
\end{spec}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Compiling such a snippet fails with:

```
./test.tex:308: Incompatible glue units.
\reset@color ->\beamer@lastskip =\lastskip 
                                           \edef \beamer@lastskiptexta {\the...
l.308 \end{frame}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Agda mode, the alerted region contains an occurrence of `\;`, as you
can observe if you look at the generated code:

```
\>[17]{}\begin{alertenv}\Varid{importantaspect}\;\end{alertenv}{}\<[E]%
```

This is triggering the error (it's a muskip and apparently something tries to put it into a
normal skip register, leading to the incompatibility error; however, I don't currently
completely understand who's responsible). One can argue that lhs2TeX shouldn't put the skip
there in the first place.

I can see two workarounds.

(1) Put another skip in that's easier to digest:

```
somefunction :  {-"\begin{alertenv}"-}importantaspect{-"\hskip0pt\end{alertenv}"-}
```

(2) Avoid the skip from being inserted by using a different formatting mechanism, for example

```
%format Importantaspect = "\alert{" importantaspect "}"
```

and then

```
somefunction :  Importantaspect
```

Comment: I updated the question with a minimally complete example. Two aspects were missing from the original question: A second line and `--agda`.

Comment: I've adapted the answer.